# Switch() does not work with Math.random() numbers

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am trying to make a function that involves switch() and gives me answers on specific, randomly generated numbers. Somehow my function does not run the case it is supposed to run. It only gives me the default case, no matter what the number is.

This is my code:

```
var i;
var girl;

function response() {
    var girl = prompt("What girl do you like?");
    var r = (Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1) + 1).toFixed(0);
    var i = r;

    switch(i) {
        case (i == 1):
            alert(girl + " likes you as a friend.");
            break;

        case (i == 2):
            alert(girl + " does not really like you.");
            break;

        case (i == 3):
            alert(girl + " has a crush on you.");
            break;

        case (i == 4):
            alert(girl + " wants you to ask her out.");
            break;

        default:
            console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: `toFixed` converts to a string, so you might want to use `case '1':`, `case '2':`, etc. Also, your range won't cover all cases, you might want to use `var i = (Math.random() * 4 + 1).toFixed(0);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how a switch works. It compares the value for each `case` to the `switch`.

Essentially now, it is comparing the value of `i` multiple times to boolean values (the result of, for example `i == 1`).

Also, your randomness doesn't become *more random* by adding arithmetic with static values into the value like you did. You should replace it with `4`. You also should use something like `Math.ceil()` (since you're ignoring the `0` value, which is also probably not a good idea), not `toFixed()` which returns a string.

You also don't need the parenthesis around the values to compare. If you know the range of the random number, you also probably don't need a default case (since you cover every possibility already).

You can also use `r` directly, no need to reassign it.

Your variables are also local to your function, so probably don't need them at the top.

Here is how I would re-write this:

```
function response() {
    var girl = prompt("What girl do you like?");
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

    switch(r) {
        case 0:
            alert(girl + " likes you as a friend.");
            break;

        case 1:
            alert(girl + " does not really like you.");
            break;

        case 2:
            alert(girl + " has a crush on you.");
            break;

        case 3:
            alert(girl + " wants you to ask her out.");
            break;

    }
}
```

...or even...

```
function response() {
    var answerSuffixes = [
        " likes you as a friend.",
        " does not really like you.",
        " has a crush on you.",
        " wants you to ask her out."
    ];
    var girl = prompt("What girl do you like?");
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * answerSuffixes.length);

    alert(girl + answerSuffixes[r]);
}
```

Comment: But if the i value is in fact let's say 3, shouldn't it be true for i == 3? Is it only possible with if statements then?  E: Thank you :)

Comment: Update: I tried your code (but added the part from @Nina Scholz). Thank you! It works now :)

Answer (score 1):

The case statement in Javascript already does a match on the target `i`:

```
switch(i) {
        case 1:
            alert(girl + " likes you as a friend.");
            break;

        case 2:
            alert(girl + " does not really like you.");
            break;

        case 3:
            alert(girl + " has a crush on you.");
            break;

        case 4:
            alert(girl + " wants you to ask her out.");
            break;

        default:
            console.log(i);
    }
```

So, there is no need to have compare expressions in each `case`.

Answer (score 0):

[`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) is comparing strict.

You need either

```
switch (i) {
    case 1:
        alert(girl + " likes you as a friend.");
        break;
```

Or

```
switch (true) {
    case i === 1:
        alert(girl + " likes you as a friend.");
        break;
```

Comment: The second one is very un-intuitive, if one of developers in my team wrote that I'd tell them to redo it

Comment: @Liam, maybe, but if there are mixed types, then it would go.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a switch, the variable used is compared to each case, so evaluations are not necessary.

Also it may help to parse your answer from 'r' into an integer for the sake of keeping the variable types in check.

```
function response() {
    var girl = prompt("What girl do you like?");
    var r = parseInt((Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1) + 1).toFixed(0));
    var i = r;

    switch(i) {
        case 1:
            alert(girl + " likes you as a friend.");
            break;

        case 2:
            alert(girl + " does not really like you.");
            break;

        case 3:
            alert(girl + " has a crush on you.");
            break;

        case 4:
            alert(girl + " wants you to ask her out.");
            break;

        default:
            console.log(i);
   }
}
```